# Restricting WebView to one page only

Tags: android, android-intent, android-webview

Is it possible to restrict WebViews so that when you have let's say one webview for website but you just want the view to stick to that page and only that page?

Great example is I have a twitter WebView that is following a tag. I just want the user to be able to follow that tag not be able to go deeper into twitter stuff.

It's already a pre-set link,

```
Button--> opens web view with set link to twitter.
```

So has to be some kind of check for on press or something like I think.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

something like this should do it.

```
myWebView = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webview);
myWebView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient() {
  public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url) {
    if(url.contains("somedomain.com")) {
      view.loadUrl(url);
    }
    return true;
  }
});
```

Comment: That would work only if i was getting input of urls, (sorry forgot to say that).
i don't have that i only have a button that opens up the webview with already set to the twitter tag page. so the if check would not do anything. i need to do some press checks i think if someone press something like links etc i somehow block that..

Comment: When someone presses a link shouldOverrideUrlLoading() will get called with the url that they are trying to go to...

Comment: yes it should work and i have tried it but when i press a link or so on it still goes to the link destination.

Comment: This should be `url.endsWith("somedomain.com")` to avoid certain bypasses such as `somedomain.com.attacker.com`. Should that not be a better practice?

Answer (score 1):

In-fact the above is a good solution but if you want an elaborate one. Try this one. I don't know whether this is proper solution for your query. play around with this.

```
webview.setWebViewClient(new MyWebViewClient());




private class MyWebViewClient extends WebViewClient {

        @Override
        public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url) {

             return true;
        }

        @Override
        public void onReceivedError(WebView view, int errorCode,
                String description, String failingUrl) {
            super.onReceivedError(view, errorCode, description, failingUrl);
        }

        @Override
        public void onPageStarted(WebView view, String url, Bitmap favicon) {
            super.onPageStarted(view, url, favicon);            
            if(!url.equals("your_domain_name.com/")){
                setResult(RESULT_OK);
                finish();
            }
          }

        @Override
        public void onPageFinished(WebView view, String url) {
            super.onPageFinished(view, url);
            if(!url.equals("your_domain_name.com/")){
                finish();
            }


        }
        @Override
        public void onTooManyRedirects(WebView view, Message cancelMsg,
                Message continueMsg) {
            super.onTooManyRedirects(view, cancelMsg, continueMsg);
            cancelMsg.sendToTarget();
        }

    }
```